# Cでmmapを使ったプロセス間通信

Tags: c

下記のコードはmmapを使ったプロセス間通信の例なのですが、なぜ、下記のようにするとプロセス間でデータがやり取りできるのでしょうか?

`for`以下の所で`*s`(sの先頭)が`1`か`0`になるまで待ち、その後に子プロセスでは`*s`に`0`を代入し、親プロセスでは`*(s+1) = 'a'`としています

なぜ、このような処理でプロセス間でデータのやり取りをしたことになるのでしょうか?

参考:[知ってトクするシステムコール（5）：システムコールを減らすシステムコール (2/2) - ＠IT](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1205/28/news125_2.html)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, rp=1000000;
    char *s;
    s = mmap(0, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
    *s = '0';
    if (0 == fork()) {
        for (i = 0; i < rp; i++) {
            while ('0' == *s)
                ;
            *s = '0';
        }
    }
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < rp; i++) {
            while ('1' == *s)
                ;
            *(s+1) = 'a';
            *s = '1';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

プロセス間通信という意味では、 `*(s+1) = 'a';` や `*s = '0';` や `*s = '1';` をした時点で、それは即座に相手にも見えるようになります (キャッシュ構成の影響などで遅れることもありますが)。

コードの意図としては、親プロセスと子プロセスの間で `*(s+1)` を使って `'a'` を送信した・受信したという確認のやりとりのつもりで、 `*s` に `'0'` や `'1'` を読み書きしてるのではと想像します。

このコードの別の問題点は、最適化つきでコンパイルするとまともに動かないことでしょう。次のようにコンパイルしたら fork() の後に無限ループする結果になってしまいました。

```
$ gcc -S -O3 a.c -o -
    .file   "a.c"
    .section    .text.unlikely,"ax",@progbits
.LCOLDB0:
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
.LHOTB0:
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB34:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    xorl    %r9d, %r9d
    movl    $-1, %r8d
    movl    $33, %ecx
    movl    $3, %edx
    movl    $4096, %esi
    xorl    %edi, %edi
    call    mmap
    movb    $48, (%rax)
    call    fork
.L2:
    jmp .L2     ← ここで無限ループ
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE34:
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDE0:
    .section    .text.startup
.LHOTE0:
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 5.3.1 20160413"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

少なくとも `volatile` などを追加しないと、意図したとおりには動きません。

```
    volatile char *s;
    s = (volatile char *)mmap(0, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
```

このように修正したとしても、特にシングルスレッドな実行環境ではパイプを使った場合に比べ性能が落ちるのではないかと思います。両プロセスとも OS にプリエンプトされるまで無駄にループが回り続け、タスクスイッチすることがないからです。

Answer (score 1):

参照先はタイトルなどからもわかりますように、頻繁にプロセス間通信が行われており、その際のシステムコールが実行時間に対して支配的となるような環境でのパフォーマンスチューニングです。

コードにある`while`ループは[スピンロック](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%94%E3%83%B3%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF)と呼ばれ、マルチプロセッサ環境でなおかつ非常に頻繁にプロセス間通信が行われその際のロック時間がシステムコールに対して十分短いことが期待できる場合には有効です。例えば挙げられたコードであれば２プロセスを１００万回往復しています。
逆にシングルプロセッサ環境だったり、yaegashiさんも指摘されているようにプロセス間通信の頻度が低くロック待ち時間が長くなる場合は、無駄なループを回すことによりCPU負荷を上げるだけで非効率となります。

ですので、無条件に適用できるパフォーマンスチューニングではないことを認識してください。